# Laravel UI Duplicate Email Error Integrity constraint violation: 1062

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel ui for Multi-Authentication. But when I am entering duplicate email then I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
> 'justshamsulalom2@gmail.com' for key 'customers_email_unique' (SQL:
> insert into `customers` (`name`, `reffer`, `email`, `status`,
> `ref_id`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (MSA Rahat,
> justshamsulalom2, justshamsulalom2@gmail.com, 2, UkvY5kOxlBm6bbKn9Jzm,
> $2y$10$vZAOY8mbvEk7SGDVjJ2mmuicQirSe68wT6S4ZuvcRHd7iwZvW5hQa,
> 2021-06-28 07:00:39, 2021-06-28 07:00:39))

This is my registration controller code:

```
public function submit(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'email'    => 'required|max:255|unique:users,email',
        'password' => 'required|min:8',
    ]);

    $user =  Customer::create([
        'name'     => $request['name'],
        'refer'    => $request['refer'],
        'email'    => $request['email'],
        'status'   => 2,
        'ref_id'   => Str::random(20),
        'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
    ]);

    return redirect()->intended('/user/login');
}
```

Comment: you are checking unique on users table, not on the customers table. so the validation passes.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `unique:users` with `unique:customers`, then validate via `customers` table emails.

The final code will be:

```php
$request->validate([
   'email'    => 'required|max:255|unique:customers,email',
   'password' => 'required|min:8',
]);

$user =  Customer::create([
   'name'     => $request['name'],
   'refer'    => $request['refer'],
   'email'    => $request['email'],
   'status'   => 2,
   'ref_id'   => Str::random(20),
   'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
]);

return redirect()->intended('/user/login');
```

Comment: Thank You and I have one more error. In login page if I enter wrong email or password then i don't get error message just redirect again to login page with email

Comment: @justMSARahat use this to print validation error https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors